# TypeError: messaging.sendEach is not a function

Tags: node.js, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I was using firebase-admin version "9.4.2" and recently discovered that the sendAll() and sendMulticast() are deprecated in newer versions. So I attempted to replace sendAll() with `sendEach()`, but I encountered an issue.

**TypeError: messaging.sendEach is not a function\n**

I tried updating my firebase-admin version to both "11.7.0" and "11.11.0", but it still doesn't work.

I checked the integration tests for sendEach and sendMulticast [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/pull/2130/files#diff-810f382e0a1b2ca1483ec19eafbc3d6d60419fec356114cb91cb404905b17c4bL110), and the only difference I found was the way I accessed the Messaging service.

```
const messaging = admin.messaging(app);
```

I'm also considering whether there might be a package version conflict issue. Here are other related packages:

```
"@firebase/app": "^0.6.14",
"@firebase/database-types": "^0.7.0",
"@firebase/storage": "^0.4.2"
"fcm-node": "^1.5.2",
"firebase-admin": "11.11.0",
"firebase-functions": "^3.16.0",
"typescript": "^4.6.4"
```

I would greatly appreciate any assistance. Thank you.